# How can i get my javacode output as json

Tags: java

I am reading **xlsx** file using `Apache POI`. I am able to fetch the result and **xlsx** entities count successfully. but I want to get my result in **JSON**, so that I can use this JSON data to make `google graph` or any `graph API`. I am new to java, how can I do that? Any help will be appreciated.

My code details are below.

```
package com.amiku.Excel;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelReader
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\amiku\\eclipse-workspace\\Amiku\\cloudstreams-connectors-downloads.xlsx"));

        //create workInstance that refers to .xlsx file
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

        //create a sheet  object to retrive the sheet 
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        //that is for evalute the cell type
        FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        Map<String, Integer> Details = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        int i=0;
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Row row : sheet)
        {
            for (Cell cell : row) {
                l.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                /*HashMap map = new HashMap();
                map.put(cell.getStringCellValue());*/

            }
                /*switch(formulaEvaluator.evaluateInCell(cell).getCellType())
                {*/
                /*//if cell has a numeric  format
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
                    break;

                // if cell has a string format
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                    break;
                }*/


            i++;
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < l.size(); j++) {
            if (j % 2 == 1) {

                  String var = l.get(j);

                  if (Details.containsKey(var)) {
                      Details.put(var, Details.get(var) + 1);
                  } else {
                      Details.put(var, 1);
                  }

            }

       }
       Iterator it = Details.entrySet().iterator();
       while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
            it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
       }

    }
    }
}
```

my result image of this code is here.

[image]

Comment: Try using Gson library https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: There are several libraries that are able to help you out with this issue.
one is GSON (https://github.com/google/gson) by google (which I like) and the other I have used is named Jackson (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) Jackson abide by the strictness of the JSON structure definition better than GSON although GSON is easier to use in my opion. I hope this helps, Cheers, Bram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a expandible object and add key value pair to this object ,once all of your javacode output is set into this object,

simply serialize this object to json using one of the speficied library.